# how to change admin panel settings programmatically

Tags: magento2, theme

i am using Magento 2 , In my case i want to change programmatically the instance's logo and favicon , but i can't find the right file to change them ,

> can anyone help me do that please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ***For set Logo***

**app\code\VendoreName\ModuleName\view\frontend\layout**

**default.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <body>
    <referenceBlock name="logo">
        <action method="setLogoFile">
            <argument name="logo_file" xsi:type="string">VendoreName_ModuleName::images/logo.png</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
  </body>
</page>
```

Put your logo image to this path **app\code\VendoreName\ModuleName\view\frontend\web\images** here my image file name is **logo.png**.

> ***For set fevicon icon***

> 1. Add your icons in the <your_theme_dir>/Magento_Theme/web/ directory.

> 2. In the <your_theme_dir>/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml layout file specify the paths to the icons and their sizes.
>    For example, if you added a favicon-32x32.png icon and want it to be used as a 32px x 32px favicon, your **default_head_blocks.xml** would be like following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <link src="Magento_Theme::images/logo.png" rel="icon" sizes="32x32" />
    </head>
</page>
```

> 3. Put your fevicon image into <your_theme_dir>/Magento_Theme/web/images/logo.png

***Note:- For your changes to be applied, clear the browser cache, and the following directories on the server (do not delete the .htaccess file!):**
**- pub/static**
**- all directories under var**

**I Hope This Helps You.***

Answer (score 0):

Just inject the class `\Magento\Config\Model\ResourceModel\Config $_resourceConfig` and set value for web/default/cms_home_page to desired page ‘youridentifier’.

```
public function __construct(\Magento\Config\Model\ResourceModel\Config $_resourceConfig)
    {
        $this->_resourceConfig = $_resourceConfig;
    }

        $this->_resourceConfig->saveConfig('web/default/cms_home_page', 'youridentifier', 'default', 0);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response , this work for me but just in my PC , i want to do this for all instances so i need to do it by code ?

Comment: No it will for all , if website is in live environment.

Comment: Clear Cache in magento

Comment: no it"s in my local now , so if i want to share the config it won't work there in prod

Comment: Just follow the same steps in production also, it will work there.

Comment: i want to export this config without do the same step in the prod , do you understand what i want ?

Comment: updated answer.

Comment: where should i put this change?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [DataPatch](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/data-patches.html) to update the path to both the logo and the favicon:

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace VENDOR\DataPatches\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Config\Model\ResourceModel\Config;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;

class UpdateFavicon implements DataPatchInterface
{
    /**
     * @var Config
     */
    protected $config;

    public function __construct(
        Config $config
    ) {
        $this->config = $config;
    }

    public function apply()
    {
        $config = $this->config;
        $path = 'PATHTOFILE';
        $config->saveConfig(
            'design/head/shortcut_icon',
            $path,
            ScopeInterface::SCOPE_WEBSITES,
            0
        );
    }

    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [];
    }

    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

Above is an example for changing the favicon. You can also do this for Logo by using `design/header/logo_src`.

However, in this example it is assumed there's already a logo / favicon in your server.

Comment: Thank you sir for your reply , after doing this  , and setting up the path of the custom favicon there are no changes on the favicon , still get Magento's favicon!! , where is the problem here ?

Comment: Please check if the patch has run (patch_list table) and if the data has been updated in database (core_config_data table. Did the patch run and has the data been updated?

Comment: there is no patch_list table in my database , i have change the module version in module.xml and i have run setup:upgrade , no result !!

Comment: Which version of Magento are you using? Datapatches (and the patch_list table) are available as of magento 2.3. However, If you are using an older version you can either update or apply the same logic in an UpdgradeData.

Comment: yes my version is older than 2.3 , can you update for me your question to show me how it works with upgradedata